# How to count amount of reactions in Discord.js v13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have tried so many things out, here's my current code

```
        var green = toString(msg.reactions.cache.get('').count);
        var red = toString(msg.reactions.cache.get('').count);
          
         msg.reply("Poll has ended which was created by " + msg.author.username)
         msg.reply(green + " " + red)
```

It gives this error

```
        var green = toString(msg.reactions.cache.get('').count);
                                                          ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count')

Please help!

I want it to display how many people reacted on  and .

I'm not able to do that even after asking Discord.js experts, I can't understand how to get them.

I also want them to be a string, that's why I used The toString() function.

This is for a poll/vote bot I am making.

I react to the messages and still it shows this error.

This is Discord.js v13.

Thanks!

TheThiefingKing

Comment: `msg.reactions.cache.find(r => r.emoji.identifier === 'YOUR_EMOJI')?.count` - what about this?

Comment: That isn't working, it just returns undefined or (If I convert it to a String) [object Undefined]

Answer (score 0):

```js
let msg = await message.channel.messages.fetch("974311411314475059")
let reactsSize = msg.reactions.cache.get("✅").count
message.channel.send("✅ Reacts on that message is: " + (+reactsSize))
```

You need to await message first after that you can fetch reactions.

Comment: It gives this error:

`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: You need to add async to your function. Like if it's `client.on("messageCreate", (message) => ` then you need to do it `client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => `.

Comment: Still gives the same error